# I have a dataframe full of lists with some NaNs, Is there any way I can get rid of the square bracket?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Like the title says: I have a dataframe full of List's and NaN's, all the values are Lists since I have used a defaultdict(list) because I had a few fields with multiple information.

[image: Transposed DataSet with a single record]

Now Since I have converted the dataset into a structured format I need to remove the square brackets from the dataframe. I dont want to use explode to create multiple rows but wanted to keep it in the same row under same column just with the [] removed.

I have tried the below but it fails too, and I would really appreciate if someone could help me to do this for the whole dataframe at once like using a function.

This is where I try to remove the '[]' from a single value of a single column but it just returns NaN:

[image: This is where I try to remove the '[]' from a single value of a single column but it just returns NaN]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a list like this ['orange','apple','banana'] can be converted to a string like this "['orange','apple','banana']", you can just apply a function that replaces the brackets for nothing:

```
  df['yourcolumn'] =  df['yourcolumn'].map(lambda single_item: str(single_item).replace('[','').replace(']',''))
```

Comment: This was really helpful, I feel so stupid not thinking about this earlier. Thanks mate!